# Is anybody here able to construct this example?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

I need to construct an example for such a situation:
Let $x_1,x_2$ and $v_1,v_2$ be four vectors in $\mathbb{C}^2$, so that they are mutually different from each other.

Further, there have to be $p_1,p_2,q_1,q_2$ such that all are $\in [0,1]$ and $p_1+p_2=q_1+q_2=1$ and we have that: $\sum_{i=1}^2 p_ix_ix_i^T = \sum_{i=1}^2 q_i v_i v_i^T$ (So they represent the "same map").

Remark: This should become an example that the density operator in physics is not unique in general.

Comment: So, what have you tried? Obviously, you do have uniqueness if the $x_i$ are mutually orthogonal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x_1\ne0$, $x_2=4x_1$, $v_1=2x_1$, $v_2=3x_1$, then 
$$ \sum_{i=1}^2p_ix_ix_i^T = (p_1+16p_2)x_1x_1^T= (1+15p_2)x_1x_1^T$$
and
$$ \sum_{i=1}^2q_iv_iv_i^T = (4q_1+9q_2)x_1x_1^T= (4+5q_2)x_1x_1^T$$
which allows you to readily find suitable $p_i,q_i$, e.g. $p_1=\frac23$, $p_2=\frac13$, $q_1=\frac35$, $q_2=\frac25$.